Unable to Open SQLCipher-Encrypted SQLite Database in DB Browser for SQLite
I'm working on a C# application that encrypts an SQLite database using SQLCipher. I'm able to encrypt the database and access it in my application using the correct password. However, when I try to open the encrypted database in DB Browser for SQLite, I'm unable to do so.
Steps Taken:
Encrypted SQLite database using SQLCipher in C#.
Attempted to open the encrypted database in DB Browser for SQLite.
Entered the correct password when prompted.
When I try to open the database in DB Browser for SQLite, I receive the following error message: "Incorrect key used to decrypt the database."
 string distFileName = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "dbTest1.db");

                string password = "1234";

                SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(distFileName);

                SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source={distFileName};Version=3;");

                connection.SetPassword("1234");
                connection.Open();

                // Create a table
                using (SQLiteCommand createTableCmd = new SQLiteCommand(
                           "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT, Age INTEGER);",
                           connection))
                {
                    createTableCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                connection.Close();

                SQLiteConnection connectionInsert =
                        new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source={distFileName};Version=3;password={password};");
                connectionInsert.Open();

                // Insert data into the table
                using (SQLiteCommand insertDataCmd = new SQLiteCommand(
                           "INSERT INTO MyTable (Name, Age) VALUES ('Alice', 30), ('Bob', 25), ('Charlie', 35);",
                           connectionInsert))
                {
                    insertDataCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                connectionInsert.Close();

                SQLiteConnection connectionRead =
                        new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source={distFileName};Version=3;password={password};");

                connectionRead.Open();
                // Read the data from the table
                using (SQLiteCommand selectDataCmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM MyTable", connectionRead))
                {
                    using (SQLiteDataReader reader = selectDataCmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            int id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Id"]);
                            string name = reader["Name"].ToString();
                            int age = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Age"]);

                            Console.WriteLine($"Id: {id}, Name: {name}, Age: {age}");
                        }
                    }
                }

                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                // Handle the exception, log it, or display an error message to the user.
            }
        }

Expected Behavior:
I expect to be able to open the encrypted SQLite database in DB Browser for SQLite using the correct password.
Actual Behavior:
I'm unable to open the encrypted database in DB Browser for SQLite and receive an "Incorrect key" error message.
Attempts to Solve the Problem:
Double-checked the password used to encrypt the database.
Tried opening the database in a different SQLite browser with no success.
Versions:
SQLCipher version: 4.4.3
DB Browser for SQLite version: 3.12.0
C# .NET version: 4.7.2

Does DB Browser use SQLCipher? If not then you'll never be able to open SQL Cipher encrypted databases with DB Browser

Yes, DB Browser use SQLCipher to Decrypt the Database

You probably need the raw key, not the password: https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/wiki/Encrypted-Databases

When I open a connection to read the database, does it automatically change the password or encryption key, because when I open it in a DB browser, the key doesn't open the database?

When I set the encryption key, the key opens the database in DB Browser

using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(connection))
{
cmd.CommandText = $"PRAGMA key = '{password}';";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
using this
